# Lifetime of quickblox session and how can i manage that in android

Tags: android, quickblox

I have already tried with
 `QBAuth.createFromExistentToken(token, expirationDate);`, 
but it's not working. when app is killed or in background it can again ask for login.Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Carefully read the information here [Initialize_framework](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Initialize_framework) and here [Authentication and Authorization](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#A_couple_of_words_about_Authentication_and_Authorization), it's about createFromExistentToken() and QB session valid time. Also you can find useful examples at QB samples.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.Please give me some example.I am New to Quickblox Android.